# React Native signed release builds but fails to start

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run my react native app in release mode.
The APK is signed per documentation and it worked fine the first times (both in the emulator and in a real device).

After some updates though ( adding libraries, changing the gradle config, developing more code) the release install does not work anymore:

- In debug mode all works OK (build, emulator and real phone)
- In release mode builds OK but app crashes at start (emulator and real phone)

In the logs I see the following error:

```
adb logcat

....
Unable to instantiate application com.myfakeappname.MainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myfakeappname.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList...
....
```

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml under the release folder

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="com.myfakeappname">

      <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        >

      </application>
 </manifest>
```

EDIT: adding proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Disabling obfuscation is useful if you collect stack traces from production crashes
# (unless you are using a system that supports de-obfuscate the stack traces).
-dontobfuscate

# React Native

# Keep our interfaces so they can be used by other ProGuard rules.
# See http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/466/
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip

# Do not strip any method/class that is annotated with @DoNotStrip
-keep @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip class *
-keep @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip *;
    @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip *;
}

-keepclassmembers @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters class * {
  void set*(***);
  *** get*();
}

-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule { *; }
-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule { *; }
-keepclassmembers,includedescriptorclasses class * { native <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIProp <fields>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactPropGroup <methods>; }

-dontwarn com.facebook.react.**

# okhttp

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

# okio

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Comment: Make sure you have a MainApplication in java/com/myfakeappname/ (relative to AndroidManifest) and that at the top you have:
package com.myfakeappname;

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you enabled proguard and some classes are being obfuscated so they are not found in runtime.

Try disabling it in the release configuration and try again. If you need, post your proguard.properties file.

Comment: Disabling proguard indeed worked. I am gonna edit the question with the proguar-rules.pro

Comment: The ones you posted seem OK. Those are the basic for ReactNative. Do you have any other module that could also add rules to the proguard configuration?